# How to set bitmap as customview background

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas

Created customview by extending view and arranged this in a layout.Now trying to set bitmap as customview background but didn't get how to do it pls help.
here i'm adding my main class

```
public class CreatePeeqsActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private ImageView ivImage, ivCountTimer;
private TextView tvUndo, tvNext;
private ImageView ivFont, ivSquare, ivRectangle, ivLine, ivCircle, ivOval;
PhotoSortrView photoSorter;
final Context context = this;
//EditText editTextAddText;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    photoSorter = new PhotoSortrView(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_peeqs);

    getIds();
    byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("BitmapImage");
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
            byteArray.length);


}
```

Comment: here is my customview class http://pastebin.com/2vKHhbk3

Comment: Here is my layout http://pastebin.com/sJqLbdVQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert bitmap to drawable and set as view's background like this.

```
byte[] byteArray = getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("BitmapImage");
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                byteArray.length);

        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmp);

        photoSorter.setBackground(d);

        //or

        photoSorter.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Comment: getting error : method setBackgroundDrawable is undefined